# Upper bound on first $k$ terms of binomial expansion where the variable is probability

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

If $p$ is some probability, meaning $0<p<1$, is there a good upper bound for $ \sum^{k}_{i=0} \binom{n}{i} \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{i}$ in terms of $n,k,p$ ?

There is of course the trivial bound without capturing the dependence on $k$, $  \left(1+\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{n} = \left(\frac{1}{1-p}\right)^{n} \geq  \sum^{k}_{i=0} \binom{n}{i} \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{i}$.

Comment: Well you can write this as $(1-p)^{-n} P(B \le k)$ for $B$ a $\mathrm{Bin}(n,p)$ random variable. Now if $k<np$ you're in the realm of upper bounds on Binomial tails, and there's a bunch of stuff you can use. Example, if $k$ is of the form $n(p-\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon > 0,$ then Hoeffding's inequality will give the bound $(1-p)^{-n} \exp(-2n\varepsilon^2)$. If $k \ge n(p + \varepsilon),$ for $\varepsilon \gg \sqrt{p}$, then you're not going to get something much better than the trivial bound because the binomial is concentrated near $np$.

Comment: Let $s_i = \frac{n-i}{i+1} \implies s_i \times \binom{n}{i} ~=~ \binom{n}{i+1}$.  Therefore, the change from $\binom{n}{i}\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^i$ to $\binom{n}{i+1}\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{i+1}$ is equivalent to multiplying the first term by $s_i \times \frac{p}{1-p}.$  Therefore, as $i$ ranges from $1$ through $k$, I would examine the behavior of $s_i$ versus $\frac{p}{1-p}.$

Comment: @user2661923 - Interesting, but can you elaborate on your thinking here ? What were you hoping to get from that line of investigation.

Comment: Suppose that $r < k$ and (for example) $$s_r \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right) ~\geq 1 ~> s_{(r+1)} \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right).$$  Then, with $$\{s_{(r+1)}, s_{(r+2)}, \cdots, s_k\}$$ a strictly decreasing sequence, you will have that $$\sum_{i = r+1}^k \binom{n}{i}\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^i ~< ~[k-r] \binom{n}{r} \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^r.$$

Comment: Alternatively, if no such $r$ presents itself, but (for example), you have that $$s_r \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right) \geq 2 > s_{(r+1)} \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)$$ then you will have that $$\sum_{i = r+1}^k \binom{n}{i} \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^i < [k-r]\binom{n}{r} \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^r \times \left(2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^{(k-r)}\right).$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=p/(1-p)$. Assuming $k\leq n$, your sum can be evaluated in terms of the hypergeometric function as
$$
S:=\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{n}{i}x^i=(x+1)^n-x^{k+1} \binom{n}{k+1} F\left({1,k-n+1\atop k+2};-x\right).
$$
We can see that when $k=n$ the second term vanishes leaving your trivial upper bound; thus our goal will be to make the second term smaller without making it zero. Using [transformation formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E1) for the hypergeometric function we can write
$$
F\left({1,k-n+1\atop k+2};-x\right)=(1+x)^{-1}F\left({1,n+1\atop k+2};\frac{x}{x+1}\right)>(1+x)^{-1},
$$
since $F(1,n+1; k+2;z)$ is increasing on $z\in(0,1)$ and $F(1,n+1; k+2;0)=1$. Hence,
$$
S\leq (x+1)^n-x^{k+1}(1+x)^{-1} \binom{n}{k+1},
$$
with equality when $k=n$. Your application will determine if this upper bound is good or not. Using some trial values in Mathematica shows that this bound is almost identical to $S$ for some parameters and can be much larger for others.

For example, denoting $S^\ast$ as the upper bound above we have
$$
(p,n,k)=(0.0662009, 5, 1)\implies (S,S^\ast)=(1.35447, 1.36149),
$$
while
$$
(p,n,k)=(0.628947, 5, 2)\implies (S,S^\ast)=(38.2065, 124.103).
$$
At the very least, this upper bound does as good or better than the trivial bound.